# extract date only from given timestamp in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g, database-administration

The following query:

```
select cdate from rprt where cdate <= TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';
```

return: `2013/04/27-10:06:26:794` as stored in the table.

I want to get the date only as : `27-04-2013` and get the number of days between the resul tdate and sysdate.

Comment: SELECT to_date(create_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') should work for you. Try it

Comment: `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`
pointing to cdate.

Comment: sorry. Since you are already having date you need to convert it into char. So try to_char(create_date,'DD-MM-YYYY'). It should do job for you.

Answer (score 26):

Use the function cast() to convert from timestamp to date

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as date),'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

For more info of function cast oracle11g http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions016.htm#SQLRF51256

Answer (score 11):

In Oracle 11g,
To get the complete date from the Timestamp, use this-

```
Select TRUNC(timestamp) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

To get the Year from the Timestamp, use this-

```
Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TRUNC(timestamp)) from TABLE_NAME;
```

To get the Month from the Timestamp, use this-

```
Select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRUNC(timestamp)) from TABLE_NAME;
```

To get the Day from the Timestamp, use this-

```
Select EXTRACT(DAY FROM TRUNC(timestamp)) from TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly what `TO_DATE()` is for: to convert timestamp to date.

Just use `TO_DATE(sysdate)` instead of `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS')`.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10899)

**UPDATE**:

Per your update, your `cdate` column is not real `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` type, but `VARCHAR2`. It is not very good idea to use string types to keep dates. It is very inconvenient and *slow* to search, compare and do all other kinds of math on dates.

You should convert your `cdate` `VARCHAR2` field into real `TIMESTAMP`. Assuming there are no other users for this field except for your code, you can convert `cdate` to timestamp as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- add new temp field tdate:
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD tdate TIMESTAMP;
-- save cdate to tdate while converting it:
UPDATE mytable SET tdate = to_date(cdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

-- you may want to check contents of tdate before next step!!!

-- drop old field
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN cdate;
-- rename tdate to cdate:
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME COLUMN tdate TO cdate;
COMMIT;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/125aa/1)

Comment: It throws error: `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: Well, [SQLFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10899) works fine for `sysdate`. What gives? Are you sure you are telling whole story here?

Comment: `SELECT to_date(cdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') from rprt where cdate <= TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';` give me that error

Comment: what is the data type of `cdate`? If it is `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE`, simple `TO_DATE(cdate)` will do. If it is string, you must use some format. But, you should simply convert it to real timestamp instead

Comment: Its VARCHAR2 datatype. How to convert it to real timestamp ??

Comment: I have updated my answer to add an example on how to convert data type from `VARCHAR2` to `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: you can NOT use to_date on a timestamp data type.

Comment: @ionutioio: you are most certainly wrong. Please take a look at linked SQLfiddle - it does use to_date() on timestamp field and it works just fine. Next time you should check before downvoting

Comment: @mvp, tried it myself yesterday (on oracle 11G) and for some reason it didn't work. The field was a timestamp with timezone. Sry for not checking the fiddle.

Comment: TO_DATE is for converting character data types to a DATE data type https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Answer (score 2):

try this type of format:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-rrrr') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Timestamp to Date as mentioned below, it will work for sure -

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP ('2015-04-15 18:00:22.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value from your timestamp column to come back as a date datatype, use something like this:

```
select trunc(my_timestamp_column,'dd') as my_date_column from my_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

This format worked for me, for the mentioned date format i.e. `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
SELECT to_char(query_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') as query_date 
FROM QMS_INVOICE_TABLE;
```

Comment: With this, you not have  a date. You've a Varchar2