# I do not want to consider the time (00:00:00) aspect of a datetime pull in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, alteryx

I am using the following condition to pull a certain date from a database: to_date('2015-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd' and it only returns data from that date looking like this : 2015-11-30 00:00:00.  How do I pull everything and not just data from that specific time during the day?

Comment: Check this thread out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535620/extract-date-only-from-given-timestamp-in-oracle-sql

Comment: It depends on your RDMS which you did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old; but here is an Alteryx solution: in Alteryx, even though you only pulled the date portion from SQL, if it is stored in a DateTime variable in Alteryx, then it will still give you the time portion. Try forcing it to a "Date" variable (e.g. run it through a Select tool and force the data type to Date).  That will remove the time portion within Alteryx and also any output files it generates.